# Configuring Elicpse and SVN for multiple repositories

Tags: eclipse, svn, authentication, repository

I'm using Elipse (Galileo) with the Subversive plugin.

When I set `SVNPath` in apache httpd.conf I can get a connection to my repos from Eclipse. This works fine:

```
<Location /repos>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath c:/SVN/MyProject
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion repository"
   ...
</Location>
```

But when I use `SVNParentPath` it errors:

"Location information has been specified incorrectly.
svn:OPTIONS of'/repos': 403 Forbidden (http://localhost)"

This is what I've got in my config file

```
<Location /repos>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath c:/SVN
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion repository"
   ...
</Location>
```

If I add `SVNListParentPath on` it crashes apache.

It works as expected in the browser (with SVNListParentPath on), ie, I get all respositories listed at localhost/repos - so the authentication is fine - the problem only occurs in Eclipse.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was going about it the wrong way by specifying an http URL when working with local repos. The easiest way to get multiple local repos into Eclipse is simply use, eg, file:///c://svn/project for each project.

I got no further with Eclipse Galileo and SVNListParentPath - this might be an Eclipse issue. Perhaps with Helios it will work as expected.